# Convert string of date to datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/data.txt', keep_default_na=True, sep='\t', na_values='?', nrows=10000)


data['Start_date'] = data.groupby(['Stock'])['Dates'].transform('min')


data['Start_date'] = pd.datetime(data['Start_date'])
```

`Start_date` is an object type column which containts dates (e.g. 2018-01-03) and I want to convert it a datetime object.

I take this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/OGP_project/trial.py", line 15, in <module>
    data['Start_date'] = pd.datetime(data['Start_date'])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 118, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `pd.datetime()` with `pd.to_datetime()`.

Comment: Haha, a quite idiotic mistake of mine but I did not notice that; thanks!